# Get Coproduct from choice

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-macros, type-level-computation

I am trying to find a way, in shapeless, to prove that a given product type extends no sealed trait, and hence does not belong to any coproduct. Given the following sealed trait hierarchy:

```
  sealed trait Foo
  case class Bar(a: Char) extends Foo
  case class Baz(b: Int)  extends Foo
```

I know I can use `shapeless.ops.coproduct.Basis` to prove that a given choice, or subsequence of choices, belongs to a co-product. Eg:

```
import shapeless._

type L = Bar :+: Baz :+: CNil

implicitly[ops.coproduct.Basis[L, Bar :+: CNil]]
```

What I am after now, is an operation to get the coproduct from a choice. Eg. given `Bar` or `Baz`, I would like to get back `L`, or alternatively, the type of the sealed base trait `Foo`.

Is this something that shapeless can do? alternatively, is it possible to do it with macros?

**Update:**

I ended up writing a fairly involved implicit macro...

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

trait SealedBaseTraitOf[A] {
  type Repr
}

object SealedBaseTraitOf {
  def materializeImpl[A](c: whitebox.Context)(implicit tag: c.WeakTypeTag[A]): c.Expr[SealedBaseTraitOf[A]] = {
    import c.universe._
    val a           = weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol
    val baseClasses = a.asClass.baseClasses
    val maybeBaseTrait =
      baseClasses
        .find(t => t.asClass.isTrait && t.asClass.isSealed)
        .map(_.asType.name)

    val repr = maybeBaseTrait.map(t => tq"$t").getOrElse(tq"Nothing")
    println(s"Got a repr: $repr")
    c.Expr[SealedBaseTraitOf[A]](q"""
        new SealedBaseTraitOf[$a] {
          type Repr = $repr
        }
      """)
  }

  implicit def materialize[A]:SealedBaseTraitOf[A] = macro materializeImpl[A]
}
```

Putting all together, the macro can be used as follows:

```
  case class ExtendsNothing(a: Int)

  sealed trait X
  case class ExtendsX(b: Char) extends X

  import shapeless._

  val bt1 = the[SealedBaseTraitOf[ExtendsNothing]]
  implicitly[bt1.Repr =:= Nothing]

  val bt2 = the[SealedBaseTraitOf[ExtendsX]]
  implicitly[bt2.Repr =:= X]

  val coprodX   = Generic[X]
  val coprodBt2 = Generic[bt2.Repr]

  implicitly[coprodX.Repr =:= coprodBt2.Repr]
  implicitly[ops.coproduct.Basis[coprodBt2.Repr, ExtendsX :+: CNil]]
```

While getting close to a solution, I am still hoping to find something a bit less involved, possibly which doesn't involve using macros.

Comment: What if there are several such traits?
`  sealed trait Foo0;
  sealed trait Foo extends Foo0;
  sealed trait Foo1;
  sealed trait Foo2;
  case class Bar(a: Char) extends Foo with Foo1;
  case class Baz(b: Int)  extends Foo with Foo2`

Comment: I don't think such macro exists in shapeless. I guess this can be done with macros or reflection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067387/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-direct-parents-of-a-classsymbol-in-macro-context http://grokbase.com/t/gg/scala-user/134qe1zx67/macros-inspecting-parent-types-of-the-enclosing-type

Comment: @DmytroMitin I guess in that circumstance it would be enough to identify "lowest upper bound" (i.e. `Foo`). However, that implies we can statically figure out the order in which traits are extended.